# Scrapy code using python giving result for one website and not for another website

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

**When i am executing this code i am getting result in the form of {[text1,author1,tag1],[text2,author2,tag2],...}**

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for quote in response.css('div.quote'):
            yield {
                'text': quote.css('span.text::text').extract_first(),
                'author': quote.css('small.author::text').extract_first(),
                'tags': quote.css('div.tags a.tag::text').extract(),
            }
```

**But, in the same code for another URL (below) i am getting result as {[name1,name2,..],[city1,city2,...]}
I want to have it in the form of {[name1,city1],[name2,city2],...] as it wah happening for the above code.**

```
import scrapy
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "student"
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.engineering.careers360.com/colleges/list-of-engineering-colleges-in-karnataka?sort_filter=alpha',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for students in response.css('div.list-pages'):
            yield {
                'name': students.css('div.title a::text').extract(),
                'city': students.css('div.clg-state a::text').extract(),                   
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your students selector is faulty:

```
for students in response.css('div.list-pages'):
```

This only selects the whole page.
What you are looking for here I think is:

```
for students in response.css('li.search-result'):
```

Comment: Thank you Granitosaurus.

Comment: @Yash no problem. Feel free to click the accept answer button to the left if you find it sufficent!

Comment: Granitosaurus please could help me out this one too.. Would be thankful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476674/how-to-crawl-data-from-the-linked-webpages-on-a-webpage-we-are-crawling